# How to make a two column layout where the right column is outside of the container?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a simple two column layout, where the right column is out of the container but still makes the container height expand.By using position:absolute it goes were it should but dosent expand.

This is the html code

// Note: I dont add the head tag to save space in here :)

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="container">

            <div id="left">


            </div>
                            <div id="right">


                            </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the css code

```
#container {
            width:900px;
            margin:0 auto;
}

#left {
        width:700px;
        float:left;}

#right{
        width:230px;
        margin-left:760px;
        position:absolute;
}
```

I cant use float:right, because it will floated to the right of the container. Maybe the structure has to be different I dont know.

Comment: you have a typo in #container margin:o auto; change to margin:0 auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a `position: relative` on `#right`, and giving it a `margin-left` greater than the width of the container: http://jsfiddle.net/8MEqL/